# How to add multiple checkboxes in multiple columns (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView with multiple columns. More precisely, the ListView contains 8 columns. 2 of them should be filled with checkboxes.

Currently only the first column contains checkboxes. It is defined as follows:

```
While Not rs.EOF
   //first column with checkboxes
   ListViewCustomer.ListItems.Add , , rs("Id")
   ListViewCustomer.ListItems(ListViewCustomer.ListItems.Count).tag = rs("Status")
   //second column etc.     
   ListViewCustomer.ListItems(ListViewCustomer.ListItems.Count).ListSubItems.Add , , rs("name")
   ....
   //Here is the second column, which doesn't display the checkboxes
   ListViewCustomer.ListItems(ListViewCustomer.ListItems.Count).ListSubItems.Add , , IIf(IsNull(rs("date_from")), "", rs("date_from"))
   ListViewCustomer.ListItems(ListViewCustomer.ListItems.Count).tag = rs("Status2")
Wend
```

Do anyone have an idea how to add the checkboxes in the last column?

EDIT:

Is it possible to realize this column with adding via `.Controls`?

Comment: As far as I understand each row is one record in a ListBox, so you can select one record, not a subrecord. Based on this, I would think it is not possible.

Comment: @ib11 That cannot be. It must be possible to add several checkboxes in several columns.

Comment: Put range say $A$1:$c$10 in input box.~Sub InsertCheckBoxes()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "New_Experiments"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set Ws = Application.ActiveSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    With Ws.CheckBoxes.Add(Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
        .Characters.Text = Rng.Value
    End With
Next
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: I have mentioned code for creating multi column check boxes in the worksheet range . Perhaps the concepts involved there can be adapted to your situation. It works for me and creates check boxes in each cell of the range on the worksheet.

Comment: @skkakkar Thanks for your comments. But I'm using UserForms in my excel-based application. In this UserForm is called the ListView which contains a table of columns.

Comment: No, it is not possible per the documentation. One checkbox per item (=row). See my answer for a custom box, as well as the links for the documentation. Also would appreciate if you'd accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `ListView` is a [more expanded version of the ListBox control.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
See [ListBox control on msdn as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251523.aspx).

They both display records of rows (the ListView has more advanced formatting options). This however means that a record is a row. Therefore you select a row when you select one of the items.

The function of the checkbox is to allow the user to mark the row(s) that is the records(s) he selects.

Thus there is only one checkbox per row, at the front of the row.

Consider this code (this is Excel 2003 VBA, but gives you the idea):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim MyArray(6, 8)
    'Array containing column values for ListBox.

    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 8
    ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended

    'Load integer values MyArray
    For i = 0 To 5
        MyArray(i, 0) = i
        For j = 1 To 7
            MyArray(i, j) = Rnd
        Next j
    Next i

    'Load ListBox1
    ListBox1.List() = MyArray

End Sub
```

You could do a custom `ListBox` or `ListView` if you really want. You could create a frame and put Labels and CheckBoxes on it. This is the only way to do this in Excel2003 where I tested. The `ListBox` object has no `Controls` child.

But this is more like a datagrid and not really a `ListBox` or `ListView` which by definition are a listing of records (rows).

**Update:**

I saw your update and that you really want to place the `CheckBox` at the end of the row.

If you only want one checkbox at the last row, you could do this custom checkbox. Again this is written for the `ListBox`, so need to convert it to your `ListView` if you want to.

Still requires a custom handling, but I had some time, so I did this code. See if you like it:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    ListBox1.List(i, 3) = ChrW(&H2610)
Next i

ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3) = ChrW(&H2611)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim MyArray(5, 3)
'Array containing column values for ListBox.

ListBox1.ColumnCount = 4
ListBox1.MultiSelect = 0
ListBox1.ListStyle = 0


    'Load integer values MyArray
    For i = 0 To 5
        MyArray(i, 0) = i
        For j = 1 To 2
            MyArray(i, j) = Rnd
        Next j
        MyArray(i, 3) = ChrW(&H2610)
    Next i

    'Load ListBox1
    ListBox1.List() = MyArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try out your approach. Could you please explain me the purpose of `ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended`? Why I need a multi selection?

Comment: @yuro Well, you can check in the help, I really like the context help (F1) of VBA. I learned almost everything from that. You highlight the word you want to look up and press F1. But `MultiSelect` just gives you options to let the user choose more rows at the same time. Experiment with it and you will see. Now I posted a new code for fun that puts a custom checkbox in the last column!

Comment: Many thanks for your support. I will try it and mark your answer if it is helpful for my example! :)

Comment: Well, how I understood, it is possible to add checkboxes in several columns and not only in one such as in a `ListView`, right?

Comment: To answer your question about the `ListView`. I don't think you can simply put that on a VBA UserForm. I don't know much about that, but you can read up on it on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I think you still need to customize it though anyway. I think I just don't understand what you really want to do. I you want to allow users to select individual cells in your ListBox then it is a DataGrid. But it is not VBA. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc821273-0690-4844-ab53-85820529ec0c/inserting-the-datagrid-control-excel-vba

Comment: You don't read correctly! My question was how I can `add multiple checkboxes in multiple columns` in a `ListView` and not `ListBox`!! I only have to mark your answer if it was helpful for me. But for my example it isn't the correct way.

Comment: I'm using `Excel 2010` but I have read, that ListView hasn't the possibility to add checkboxes in multiple columns.

Comment: @yuro Yes, I read the same thing. In 2003 that I used has no ListView. But it is still the same idea as the ListBox. One row is one record. So you select one record at a time, not one column of one record. You could adopt my code for the ListBox above to make a custom checkbox. Just test my code to see what I mean with custom checkbox.

Comment: OK @yuro So I expanded my answer with the data on the ListView now. See if you can apply the example I gave you to your ListView.